# Page not found error when updating CV Information

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not able to update my cv details, each time I try to update, it throws an error.

I am using Linux KUbntu 14.04 firefox.

When I clicked on submit then I am getting page not found error.

I have attached relevant screen shots.

**Update CV information:**
[image: Normal]

**Page not found error:**
[image: Bug]

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes i clear browser's cache. it happens in chrome and firefox

Comment: @Rajesh I'm unable to repro on Firefox under Windows. Can you let me know you browser details?

Comment: I am using Firefox 42.0 and chrome 47.0 on Kubntu 14.04

Comment: @Rajesh still unable to repro; is this still happening?

Comment: @DeanWard still happening

Comment: @Rajesh would you mind updating your post with a screen capture of the network tab in Chrome or Firefox with the 'Preserve Log' option checked whilst you hit the save button please? Thanks!

Comment: @DeanWard now it is working when i try to update profile it is not showing any error as of now. but don't know why error occurs before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well we're still unable to repro but we've identified the code path that was affected and fixed it. That code path is only reachable if the AJAX request had its query string stripped away. I've pushed the fix to prod so you shouldn't have any more issues.