# After adding read book on CV, site navigates to page not found

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

When adding a book that I've read on my CV, it adds the book, but navigates to page not found. This is annoying.

[Page not found after CV Edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315628/page-not-found-after-cv-edit)
[Page not found error when updating CV Information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314951/page-not-found-error-when-updating-cv-information)

Answer to these questions:

> Well we're still unable to repro but we've identified the code path that was affected and fixed it. That code path is only reachable if the AJAX request had its query string stripped away. I've pushed the fix to prod so you shouldn't have any more issues.

I say, you have not fixed it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well it's not the same bug, it's because the URL being redirected to is clearly incorrect. Looking at a fix now

Comment: I can't repro this. Can you get a screen capture of your network tab in the Chrome [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) with the Preserve Log checkbox checked please?

Comment: @DeanWard I'm unsure what you want. Please see me edit

Comment: Perfect, that gives me enough to go on. Thanks!

Comment: @DeanWard I'm wondering if it's my extensions banning various things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report! When there were no books left to import we attempted to automatically return you to your CV by searching for an anchor tag with the `cancel` CSS class and using its URL.

Unfortunately, on the import page we neglected to use the `cancel` class and the code silently failed.

Fix is now pushed to prod!